# How to find dominant species per plot?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data file with the vegetation cover per species (~80 species in total) in 120 plots. I want to find which species (in decreasing order of cover percentage) are responsible for at least 80% of the vegetation cover.

For instance:

```
       Species A   Species B  Species C  Species D
Plot 1    50%         35%         10%       5%
Plot 2    20%         30%         40%      10%
Plot 3    85%          5%         15%       0%
```

So the outcome will be:

```
       Species
Plot 1    A B
Plot 2   C B A
Plot 3     A
```

etc.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach using `tidyverse`.

First, put your `Species` columns into long format with `pivot_longer`. Then, within each `Plot`, arrange the percentages in descending order for computing cumulative sum with `arrange`.

You can use `slice` to take percentages up to crossing the 80% threshold for minimum vegetation cover. Finally, you can use `summarise` to put the `Species` together for each `Plot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Species")) %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cum_value = cumsum(value)) %>%
  slice(1:min(which(cum_value >= 80))) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Species = paste(name, collapse = " "))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Plot   Species                      
  <chr>  <chr>                        
1 Plot_1 Species_A Species_B          
2 Plot_2 Species_C Species_B Species_A
3 Plot_3 Species_A
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Plot = c("Plot_1", "Plot_2", "Plot_3"), Species_A = c(50L, 
20L, 85L), Species_B = c(35L, 30L, 5L), Species_C = c(10L, 40L, 
15L), Species_D = c(5L, 10L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution (can be greatly improved, but I leave that to you).
Let's say this is your data:

```
species <- data.frame(Species_A = c(50, 20, 80), Species_B = c(35, 30, 5),
                  Species_C = c(10, 40, 15), Species_D = c(5, 10, 0))
row.names(species) <- c("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3")
```

Now, let's define your threshold (let's say, 80%):

```
threshold <- 80
```

Finally, a loop-like answer:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(species)){
 Plot_i <- species[i, ]
 order_i <- sort(Plot_i, decreasing = T)
 j <- 1
 while(sum(order_i[1:j])<threshold){
  j <- j + 1
}
  print(names(order_i[1:j]))

}
```

Please not that:

-This prints the answer, but does not assign it to an object

-You should avoid the use of `for` and `while` loops in R, as the `apply` family usually works clearer and faster

-I am assuming that your database has only numbers, not the weird % symbol, which will bring lots of problems

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do the last step, but this might help you abit forward:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#data
df <- structure(list(Plot = c("Plot1", "Plot2", "Plot3", "Plot1", "Plot2", 
"Plot3", "Plot1", "Plot2", "Plot3", "Plot1", "Plot2", "Plot3"
), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Species.A", "Species.B", "Species.C", 
"Species.D"), class = "factor"), Measurement = c(50L, 20L, 85L, 
35L, 30L, 5L, 10L, 40L, 15L, 5L, 10L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")

#go from wide to long data
df <- gather(df, Species, Measurement, Species.A:Species.D, factor_key = TRUE)

#order values per group (highest measurements first)
df <- df[order(df$Plot, df$Measurement, decreasing = TRUE),]

#calculate the cumulative measurements
df <- df %>% group_by(Plot) %>% mutate(Cumulative = ave(Measurement, Plot, FUN = cumsum))

df
```